# Try...Catch...Finally - can "ex" tell you where the exception happened?

Tags: .net, exception, try-catch

In the following:

```
Try
    Some code, which throws an exception
Catch ex as Exception
    Debug.Print(ex.[some property which contains the exception location]
End Try
```

are there any properties of the ex variable which can tell you the line or even procedure in which the exception occurred? I'm using vb.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ex.StackTrace` usually contains the line number in which the exception is thrown.

This is usually in the format of:

> at Project.Class.Method() in c:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Project\Namespace\Class.cs:line 178

Comment: Wow, I just realised it's a "stack trace" and shows the full breadcrumb trail to the erroneous procedure, then line. That's awesome!

Comment: It's a nice feature, there's also a more complete way of displaying the entire message. C#: `Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString);` I think the VB implementation of this is the same minus the semicolon. I hope someone will correct me if not, as I'm not usually a VB user!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need ex.StackTrace or ex.TargetSite

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.targetsite(v=vs.110).aspx

I've only used these properties myself in C# but this should be the same across all .NET.